How to resume suspended upgrade from ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04?
I was upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04 using Software Updater when a window popped up showing a message regarding Thunderbird with a button labeled Next. When I clicked Next, the window did not respond. After clicking Next a few more times, another window opened with two options: either Force quit or Wait.
After I clicked 'Wait' for a while, this same message re-appeared repeatedly and I chose 'Force quit'. Then the upgrade froze as shown in the screenshot at least 40 minutes.
What do I do now?
Thanks in advance,
Screenshot of suspended upgrade

It's not suspended; it's locked up. You'll need to restart the system, and I hope you are able to clear or resume the update. It's been many years since I had to resume an update within Ubuntu.  You'll need to do some research on how to do that.

Thanks for your reply.

Sorry for this delayed reply as there were few other issues too beyond the upgrade. The upgrade resumed itself in its own but 'one eternity later'.
